# when it goes to https:/... directly it is missing the referer part

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect, rewrite, url-routing

it's all about cookies ,it suppose redirect to ?referer_id=186 every time which is refresh the cookies of new logo but i notices when user delete or clear the history of Brower and try to visit the website by https the cookies not refresh again

you can try by visit

`https://gps.tolivery.com` and then delete the cookies and again visit the same link , you will notices the cookies changed and ?referer_id=186 ignored , to fix this i have to visit without ssl

`http://gps.tolivery.com` or using ssl with `?referer_id=186` 
`https://gps.tolivery.com/?referer_id=186`

i just want always the https by `this link https://gps.tolivery.com`

*redirect to ?referer_id=186 automatic* to refresh the cookies like the same

behavior of  http (gps.tolivery.com) whether user delete cookies or not

*configuration:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1?referer_id=186 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^      https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you please edit that and include some punctuation and paragraphs? Are you asking how to always add a specific referer_id when people visit your server? Can you explain the use case a bit? Perhaps there are other ways to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: i just done it , and  the summary is when going to http://.... redirects to https://...?referer_id=186 and that is ok. But if the user goes to https://... directly he is missing the referer part and that's my issue

Comment: Please add your configuration to the question.

Comment: ok i shared the configuration